# Retrieve value from stored procedures in a C# Windows App

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I am trying to display the value returned by a stored procedure in a C# WPF App. The user types in their card number, clicks "Submit" and the following code runs:

```
if (textBox1.Text != "")
{
    long numCardNumber; //Card number (card number scanned and converted to a number)
    string strCardNumber; // Card number (card number stored as string)
    char[] MyChar = {';','?'};

    label2.Text = textBox1.Text.TrimEnd(MyChar); // Trims end
    label2.Text = label2.Text.TrimStart(MyChar); //Trims beginning

    strCardNumber = label2.Text; 

    try //try and convert the string to a number (if valid numerical characters
    {
        numCardNumber = Convert.ToInt64(strCardNumber);
        label1.Text = "Your number is: " + label2.Text; // Scanned " + numOfTimeScanned + " times"; 


    }
    catch(FormatException) // thrown if input characters are not valid numeric
    {
        label1.Text = "NOT A VALID CARD INPUT!";
    }

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TestServer;Initial Catalog=Testdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=testuser;Password=testpass");

    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GW_MAGTOOCR", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@iMAG", SqlDbType.Char);
    param.Value = label1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    SqlParameter retval = cmd.Parameters.Add("@iMAG", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    int returnvalue = (int)cmd.Parameters["@iMAG"].Value;


} //END IF
else
{
    label1.Text = "Nothing Submitted!";
}
```

The following are the 2 stored procedures involved. Should be returning an integer

Stored procedure 1 called GW_MAGTOOCR that is called from code (which in turn, calls the stored procedure 2 called CDS_INTTOHEX).

**STORED PROCEDURE 1:**

```
USE [Testdb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GW_MAGTOOCR]  */
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER procedure [dbo].[GW_MAGTOOCR](
  @iMag char(18),
  @oOCR varchar(10) output
)
--WITH ENCRYPTION
as

declare
  @vTStr   varchar(9),
  @vPrefix char(2),
  @vCRC    varchar(2),
  @vTemp   int
begin
  IF isnumeric(@iMag) = 0
    Begin
      Set @oOcr = Null
      Return
    End
  -- get the prefix
  select @vTemp = convert(int, substring(@iMag, 4, 3))
  execute CDS_INTTOHEX @vTemp, @vTStr output
  select @vPrefix = substring(@vTStr, 7, 2)
  -- get the CRC
  select @vTemp = convert(int, substring(@iMag, 7, 2))
  execute CDS_INTTOHEX @vTemp, @vTStr output
  select @vCRC = substring(@vTStr, 8, 1)
  select @vTemp = convert(int, substring(@iMag, 9, 2))
  execute CDS_INTTOHEX @vTemp, @vTStr output
  select @vCRC = @vCRC + substring(@vTStr, 8, 1)
  -- get the account #
  select @vTemp = convert(int, substring(@iMag, 11, 8))
  execute CDS_INTTOHEX @vTemp, @vTStr output
  select @oOCR = @vPrefix + @vCRC + substring(@vTStr, 3, 6)
 /*select output = @vPrefix + @vCRC + substring(@vTStr, 3, 6)*/
end
```

**STORED PROCEDURE 2:**

```
USE [Testdb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CDS_INTTOHEX]  *****/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[CDS_INTTOHEX] (
  @iInteger   int,
  @oHex       varchar(9) output
) 
--WITH ENCRYPTION
as begin

  declare
    @vDec       int,
    @vHex       char,
    @vLen       int,
    @vDivisor   int,
    @vQuotient  int,
    @vRemainder int,
    @vTemp      varchar(9)
  select @vTemp = ''
  select @vQuotient = @iInteger
  select @oHex      = ''
  select @vLen      = 8
  while  @vLen > 0 begin
    select  @vLen = @vLen - 1
    select  @vDivisor = power(16, @vLen)
    select  @vDec = floor(@vQuotient / @vDivisor)
    if      @vDec < 10 select @vHex =convert(char, @vDec)
    else if @vDec = 10 select @vHex = 'A'
    else if @vDec = 11 select @vHex = 'B'
    else if @vDec = 12 select @vHex = 'C'
    else if @vDec = 13 select @vHex = 'D'
    else if @vDec = 14 select @vHex = 'E'
    else if @vDec = 15 select @vHex = 'F'
    select @vTemp = @vTemp + @vHex
    select  @vQuotient = @vQuotient - (@vDec * @vDivisor)
  end
  select @oHex = @vTemp
end
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I'm quite sure the issue lies in my C# code, as I can successfully call the stored procedure from within SQL management studio and receive the expected value back.

***EDIT***

I've updated my code a bit, I've created a simple stored proc that basically calls the first two (initially MAGTOOCR) which seems to run fine when I run it from Management Studio, now I'm just not sure if my code is calling it correctly, here is my updated code:

```
connection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CNBID", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@iMAG", SqlDbType.Char, 18); 
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            param.Value = label2.Text;

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    label2.Text = "Reading";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                label2.Text = "NOTHING READ!";
            }
```

I know the code doesn't output anything useful at the end, but I want to watch the variables while I debug. I'm sure I'm not doing something correctly above. Any help again is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the procedure to output the value of `@iMAG` you need to set the parameter direction to `Output`.

```
SqlParameter parm = cmd.Parameters.Add( "@iMAG", SqlDbType.Char);
parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

**EDIT**

You're creating the `@iMAG` parameter twice in your code. Just create it once, like this:

```
SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@iMAG", SqlDbType.VarChar); 
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
param.Value = label1.Text;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input James. I believe that is what I'm currently doing, not sure if there is another way to go about it?

Comment: You're creating the parameter twice, and there is no value set to the second `@iMAG` parameter. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks again for replying and the advice. :-)
Not sure how I pass a value to the stored procedure though. I need to pass it an 18 character int for the stored procedure to return something. Would I pass that value with the Parameters.Add statement?

Comment: Look at the second example in my answer. It adds the parameter to the command object, marks it as an output parameter, and assigns a value to the parameter.

Comment: Why is it an integer?  Are you doing calculations on it?  Also, I didn't see in the code you posted where you are actually executing the stored procedure.  Somewhere you need to call ExecuteReader or ExecuteScalar.  Your stored procedure do not seem to SELECT or RETURN anything.

Comment: I may need to use the following SQL command to return a value: '"select cardnumber from cds_card card where cardnumber = (select @oOCR)'. Sorry for my excessively noob-ish questions! I have not worked with stored procs for years.

Comment: If the `@iMag` parameter is supposed to return a value, you need to set `@iMag` before the procedure finishes.

Comment: @JamesJohnson - Thanks for the help! I've reworked a few things. However not sure if I should use the ExecuteReader() function, or ExecuteScalar() to obtain the value? I've edited my original post above. Thanks again all.

Comment: @Energata you can  `ExecuteScalar` only if the stored procedure returns exactly 1 value (1 row, 1 column). If you return more than one column in your proc, you need to use `ExecuteReader`

Comment: @Icarus Yep, 'ExecuteScalar()' finally worked :-) Had to modify 'param' variable to 'ParameterDirection.Input' instead of 'ParameterDirection.Output'